# Durations of tasks -- how to generate gantt-like chart from CSV

Tags: excel, csv, gantt-chart

I have this CSV data:

```
Task,From,To,Duration
Task 1, 2011-02-20 12:30.12, 2011-02-20 12:32.33, 3422
Task 2, 2011-02-17 15:39.32, 2011-02-18 9:05.23, 345
Task 3, 2011-02-15 09:02.09, 2011-02-18 9:05.24, 3453455
```

And I would like to generate something like a gantt chart showing when task has started and ended with seconds granularity.

Is there any tool of Excel template which can do this job easily?

I dont want to set up gantt charts in excel every time I paste data. 
Just to load CSV into some app. and see. :)

Thank you
Martin

Comment: Have you googled Excel Gantt chart? there are lots of templates and app, some paid, some free

Comment: Yes, but in those templates you have to write/define tasks and data by yourself, cannot import or read from file. I would need some add. enhancment.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found one good solution:

I am using graphical tool GNUPlot (http://www.gnuplot.info/). Graph is generated thanx to this great python script:

http://wiki.mn.wtb.tue.nl/wonham/gantt.py

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this `CSV` to `Gnome Planner` converter [script in Python](https://gist.github.com/nmz787/61a8e8d774913a2af90471b478a09451)

Here it is in action:
[image: Here it is in action]

Answer (score 0):

An Windows App called WinCalendar converts CSV or Excel data to Gantt Charts in Excel.  See: [wincalendar.com/Gantt-Chart](http://www.wincalendar.com/Gantt-Chart)

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite